# Using Vue3 & nuxt - trying to display an OpenLayers Map

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, nuxt.js, openlayers

I wonder if someone can help me.

I have a Vue3 application and i'm trying to load the OpenLayers map into a component and then pull it into a page.

The process of setting up the view page and the basic component seems to work fine, but when I try and pull the map in, all I get it a blank space.

I have spent some time looking online, but it seems help with OpenLayers seems somewhat limited, and it's becoming a little frustrating as no errors seem to be returned, so it makes no sense.

For starters, I have inside the nuxt.config.ts updated it to

```
nuxt.config.ts
```

and run npm install and restarted the dev server

My view page called index.vue looks like

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>My Nuxt.js App</h1>
    <MyMap />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyMap from '~/components/MyMap.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MyMap
  }
}
</script>
```

and the code from my component fle, which contains the map and failed to render it is

```
<template>
    <ol-map style="height:400px; width:400px">
      <ol-view
        ref="view"
        :center="center"
        :rotation="rotation"
        :zoom="zoom"
        :projection="projection"
        @zoomChanged="zoomChanged"
        @centerChanged="centerChanged"
        @resolutionChanged="resolutionChanged"
        @rotationChanged="rotationChanged"
      />

      <ol-tile-layer>
        <ol-source-osm />
      </ol-tile-layer>
    </ol-map>

    <div>
      center : {{ currentCenter }} zoom : {{ currentZoom }} resolution :
      {{ currentResolution }} rotation : {{ currentRotation }}
    </div>
  </template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue'
import Map from 'ol/Map'
import View from 'ol/View'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay'
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'
import 'ol/ol.css'

export default {
  setup () {
    const center = ref([40, 40])
    const projection = ref('EPSG:4326')
    const zoom = ref(8)
    const rotation = ref(0)

    return {
      center,
      projection,
      zoom,
      rotation
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentCenter: this.center,
      currentZoom: this.zoom,
      currentResolution: this.resolution,
      currentRotation: this.rotation
    }
  },
  methods: {
    zoomChanged (currentZoom) {
      this.currentZoom = currentZoom
    },
    resolutionChanged (resolution) {
      this.currentResolution = resolution
    },
    centerChanged (center) {
      this.currentCenter = center
    },
    rotationChanged (rotation) {
      this.currentRotation = rotation
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

this has mostly been lifted directly from

https://vue3openlayers.netlify.app/componentsguide/view/

Does anyone know why the map fails to render?

Thank you so much for any help

I have tried searching Google and Forums for help and also looking on YouTube for any video tutorials, but there seems limited information

Comment: Do you have any error showing in the console ? Or anything that could help us guess the issue ?

Comment: Hi, nope, no errors at all, that is what's so strange

Answer (score 0):

If you added OpenLayers as plugin:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import Openlayers from "vue3-openlayers";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Openlayers);
});
```

Try to add mode: "client" to your plugin definition in nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  plugins: [{ src: "~/plugins/vue3-openlayers.js", mode: "client" }],
});
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this

so does that import export code go into the view page?

Comment: When added to nuxt.config it actually flags "Internal server error: Failed to resolve import" asking me if the file "vue3-openlayers.js" actually exists. Although it's true, the file does not exist, the npm packages were imported and I have got OpenLayers working already on a different component. Very strange

Comment: You should create separate file in "/plugins/vue3-openlayers.js" with defineNuxtPlugin as in my answer. It's recommended way of adding plugins to Nuxt. It will create global plugin definition. The "mode" client should prevent it from errors such "No window available" etc

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much that seems to work, my only issue is that I use typescript, so when I compile the js file using your answer it fails to load the page at all and returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default" in the console. Any suggestion on how to use your answer in typescript that will compile the js correctly? Thanks again

Comment: Maybe try to add `build: { transpile: ["vue3-openlayers"] },` to your `defineNuxtConfig({})` in the nuxt.config